# to return only highest value records

Tags: sql, sql-server, median

Hi I'm trying to return the records for the value which has most occurrences. With this query

```
SELECT b.section,c.valuename
      ,count(a.value) as counts

  FROM [dbo].[SurveyResponse] a
  JOIN [dbo].[Questions] b ON A.qid=b.qid
  join [dbo].[SurveyValues] c on a.value=c.value
  where profileid=2
  group by b.section,c.valuename
  order by 1,2
```

I get these results ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9hlw.jpg)):

```
+ -- + ----------------------- + ----------------- + ------ +
|    | section                 | valuename         | counts |
+ -- + ----------------------- + ----------------- + ------ +
| 1  | Customer & Markets      | Completely Agree  | 2      |
| 2  | Customer & Markets      | Somewhat Agree    | 4      |
| 3  | Data and Analytics      | Completely Agree  | 3      |
| 4  | Data and Analytics      | Somewhat Disagree | 3      |
| 5  | Leadership & Culture    | Completely Agree  | 2      |
| 6  | Leadership & Culture    | Somewhat Agree    | 4      |
| 7  | Organization & Talent   | Completely Agree  | 3      |
| 8  | Organization & Talent   | Somewhat Agree    | 2      |
| 9  | Organization & Talent   | Somewhat Disagree | 1      |
| 10 | Products & Services     | Completely Agree  | 3      |
| 11 | Products & Services     | Somewhat Agree    | 1      |
| 12 | Products & Services     | Somewhat Disagree | 2      |
| 13 | Technology & Innovation | Completely Agree  | 3      |
| 14 | Technology & Innovation | Somewhat Agree    | 5      |
| 15 | Vision & Strategy       | Completely Agree  | 2      |
| 16 | Vision & Strategy       | Somewhat Agree    | 4      |
+ -- + ----------------------- + ----------------- + ------ +
```

From this result, I want to return the section and value name with median values of counts. For example, row 7, 8, 9, it should return row 7 with the value 3 as it has more occurrences.

Can someone please help?

Comment: The median is not he value that has the most occurrences.  Sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: maybe looking for mode

Comment: or maybe looking for median from the mode result... counts 3 (mode) for rows 3 4 7 10 13.. thus median from the mode is 7

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume -- based on the example -- that you want the highest count for each section.  That is a simple application of window functions:

```
select x.*
from (select q.section, c.valuename, count(sr.value) as counts,
             row_number() over (prtition by q.section order by count(sr.value) desc) as seqnum
      from [dbo].[SurveyResponse] sr join
           [dbo].[Questions] q
           on sr.qid = q.qid join
           [dbo].[SurveyValues] sv
           on sr.value = sv.value
      where profileid = 2
      group by q.section, c.valuename
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your query in a CTE, then you can use a correlated subquery to get your desired result.

```
; with
    CTE as ( -- CTE
        SELECT    b.section
                , c.valuename
                , count(a.value) as counts
            FROM [dbo].[SurveyResponse] a
            JOIN [dbo].[Questions] b ON A.qid=b.qid
            join [dbo].[SurveyValues] c on a.value=c.value
            where profileid=2
            group by b.section,c.valuename
    )
select Section, ValueName, counts
    from CTE a
    where ValueName = ( -- Correlated Subquery
        select top 1 ValueName
            from CTE b
            where a.Section = b.Section
            order by counts desc
    )
    order by Section
```